# How to cover a div with an image independently of its height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, mobile

(!) This question could be considered duplicated, however, did not find anything that could fit as a solution in up to 10 topics -  *I am sorry for that, I am trying to find a solution to this particular situation*;

Let me explain the problem,

I'll leave here an image that may help you understand the issue :

[image]

I have a full width div, **which height will change on page heights alteration**.
This div contains full width images covering it, so you can see in the following screenshot :

[image]

**So I tried to make it full width as well full height, independently of the parent's height**

( which is higly vulnerable to changes once its height depends on the distance between the top and bottom of the screen - So anytime we change screen's height, the referred div will as well change the div's height);

**The problem spawns here** : 
When the screen receives a ration between width and height of **1:2 (width:height)**, then, **images will re-size once the page's width** (which is img's max width) will not be enough to fill the height, not filling the div as I wished, as you can verify at following screenshot:

[image: http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0014/1091/951363/160306/43759c0a1f.jpg]

(the red part is the parent div of the image)

- I will be searching for a solution in javascript/jquery/css
- The use of the image as background is being discouraged and it did not work as I tried before
- Any tip or indication will be highly appreciated and praised;
- **If you find this topic offensive or a *rule-breaker*, please notify so I can delete this question once I do not want to spam this wonderful community**.

**Thanks in advance** ! (*accept my apologies for this long question*)

With the best wishes,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property that you're looking for is:

`background-size: cover;` (for background-image);
`object-fit: cover;` (for regular images);

*ps: the container of the object-fit picture must have `overflow: hidden`*

Comment: thanks for reminding me about that one, I've used it before - going to give a try.

Comment: updated just right now with a second property; re-check please

Comment: Thanks mate, I am checking it now and seems it works perfectly but somehow not in my case - there may be a conflict.

Comment: I'm currently there eh ! :D Give me some time to review this and every other alternative.

Comment: done ! :) Problem was that I was using percentage to define the height, and it only works with a fixed value (px).

Comment: sometimes, when % doesn't work, you can use the viewport reference vh (for height) and vw (for width). Example: `body { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; margin: 0px;`

Comment: It's a pleasure to help. I did help you today because someone did help me yesterday ;)

Comment: I was testing `object-fit: cover;` and, at least on my Chrome 49, it only works after set `overflow:hidden` to the container div.